# Converting NSNumbers saved in a plist to integers

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsnumber

Saving data:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:points];
  [array addObject:number];

  [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
  [array release];
}
```

Reading data:
BestLabel.text will display the high score. I get a warning: "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

```
-(void)LoadData{
BestLabel.center = CGPointMake(150,300);

NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    loadint = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myString35 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", loadint]; 
    BestLabel.text = myString35;
    [array release];
}
}
```

The sample code I got this from was saving and loading text fields with no problem.. I suppose I could do a string to int conversion, but that seems unnecessary. Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
```

{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
if (points > highscore){

    NSString *myString35 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", points];
    [array addObject:myString35];
}else {
    NSString *myString35 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highscore];
    [array addObject:myString35];
}


NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:GreenBlot.center.x];
[array addObject:number];
NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:GreenBlot.center.y];
[array addObject:number2];
```

And now loading with:

```
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    BestLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    highscore = [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue];


    lx = [[array objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    ly = [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
    GreenBlot.center = CGPointMake( lx,ly);


    [array release];
}
```

lx and ly are integers. I tried CGPointMake( [[array objectAtIndex:1] intValue], [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue] ) first. Same results, GreenBlot is getting centered at 0,0. Any idea why?

Comment: Is loadint an int or an NSNumber?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is use `NSNumber`'s [`intValue`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/intValue) method:

```
loadint = [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Comment: Trying this.. see main post. Attempting to set a CGPointMake with the intValues is only giving me 0,0.

Comment: 1. What type of variable is returned by GreenBlot.center.x?
2. What type of variable are lx and ly?

Answer (score 1):

You need the second line below:

```
loadint = [array objectAtIndex:0];
int score = [loadint intValue];
NSString *myString35 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", loadint];
```

If you are only saving one value, then use a NSDictionary with a key that makes it easier for you to label the value you are saving.

Comment: minor correction: [loadint integerValue] returns an `NSInteger`, which (depending on the system) may or may not be an `int`.  You'd either want to change the method call to `intValue` or change the type of `score` to `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

CGPointMake is defined:

```
CGPoint CGPointMake(
    float x,
    float y
)
```

You are taking GreenBlot.center.x which is presumably a float and feeding it to NSNumber as an int....   Go back and look at the types of your variables and change to [NSNumber numberWithFloat:...] and lx = [[array objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]; etc., as appropriate.

Also, you've created a different question in your editing of the original question.